# RPN Calculator in C++ (CodeBlocks console)

Tags: c++, calculator, rpn

I am doing an RPN calculator mostly to learn C++, however I cannot progress since I have some problems ...

1 - As in any RPN calculator I don't want to hit enter every time I enter a number. That should only happen for the first one, when the stack is empty.

Imagine that I want to do the following:
2 + 3 + 4

In RPN this should be entered as
2 ENTER
3 +
4 +

So when the code "sees" an operator (+ in this case) I should not have to hit "ENTER", the code must realize that for itself.

2 - The conversion function that I am using (string2Double), works ok if the string contains a number. However if I enter for eg. "abc", it will return 0 and this number will be pushed into the stack as if I had entered the number 0, what is not what I want to do.
To overcome that, I tried to use the flag fail() but I am not having any success passing the result to the main function.

Please find the code below.

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
void popNum(stack<double>);
double str2Double(string);

int main()
{
  string userIn=""; // User input
  stack<double> mystack;
  double retVal=0;
  stringstream ss;

  cout<<"\nWelcome to the amazing Calculator\n";

  while (userIn!="stop") {      // Exits when userIn is "stop"

    cout<<"\naCalc $ ";
    cin>>userIn;
    ss<<userIn;

    if ((cin.get()=='\n') && (userIn!="stop")){     // Executes only after an "enter" and if different from "stop"

        // Need to convert string to double, before pushing into the stack
        retVal=str2Double(userIn);
        mystack.push(retVal);

        cout<<"\t\t\tSTACK's Content";
        cout<<"\n\t\t\tLast number pushed : "<<retVal<<endl;

        popNum(mystack);
    }
    else{
        // Do nothing;
        cout<<"\nExiting !!!\n";
     }
  }


  return 0;
}

double str2Double(string userIn){
    // Converts a string into a double

    double outValue=0;
    stringstream ss;

    // read user input which is a string
    ss << userIn;

    // write the string read from the input to a double
    ss >> outValue;

    cout << "Return: " << outValue << '\n';

    cout<<"ss flag: "<<ss.fail()<<endl;
    // Return the value read (double type)
    return outValue;
}

void popNum(stack<double> mystack){
  while (!mystack.empty())
  {
     std::cout << "\n\t\t\t"<< mystack.top();
     mystack.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel by writing your own `strToDouble`?  There are several standard C++ library functions that do the job, and report failure in various ways.  One such function is [std::stod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. Do you have any suggestion regarding question 1 ?

Comment: There's no way I know of. AFAIK, the input only get's sent to your program from the console when you press enter.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for the reply. It must be a way, otherwise if you did a game for the console (eg. tetris) you would not be able to move left, right, rotate, etc.